# How to extend another extension's command in Hg?

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-extension, mercurial-convert

I want to add additional option to the `hg convert` command, which is provided by internal extension `hgext.convert`.

I try to do the following in my `__init__.py`:

```
def extsetup(ui):
    entry = extensions.wrapcommand(commands.table, 'convert', convert_cmd)
    entry[1].append(('', 'test', None, _("test option")))

def convert_cmd(...): ...
```

But after enabling my extension and running proper `hg convert --test`, I get the following error:

```
hg: unknown command 'convert'
(did you mean one of clone, recover, revert?)
```

If I print the keys of `commands.table`, I can see that there are no custom commands inside.

How can I get and extend custom command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ["Writing Mercurial Extensions"](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WritingExtensions#Command_table_setup):

> After extsetup, the cmdtable is copied into the global command table in Mercurial.

So I need to modify the command inside the extension's `cmdtable` itself. It's a little bit hacky, but works for now:

```
from hgext import convert

def extsetup(ui):
    entry = extensions.wrapcommand(convert.cmdtable, 'convert', convert_cmd)
    entry[1].append(('', 'test', None, _("test option")))
```